# What is this miniature 2-pin D-shaped connector?

Tags: connector, identification

[image: mating side]

[image: side view]

In about 1992, I built a dolls' house and bought these connectors from RS to use as ceiling roses. The picture shows the 'plug'. The plug came with a cover that screwed onto the threaded section. There was a corresponding 'socket' with two pins (which I use as the actual ceiling rose).

The pin spacing appears to be 3mm (definitely more than 2.54mm) and the plug diameter is about 5mm. The pin diameter is <1mm. The socket fitted over the plug. Sadly time (and children) have taken their toll, and this is the last plug. The heat shrink section hides a pea bulb. The sockets are the actual roses and are all glued into the doll's house, so if I can't find more similar plugs, I'll have to re-wire the whole thing.

The only markings I can find are 'EM' in a rectangle, and the digit '3' beside that. The pins are marked 'A' and 'B'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have certainly seen this type back in the old days, but don't recall the exact name/part number.

Comment: Looks a bit like a marine connector (SeaTalk) with fewer pins. Is RS Radiospares (UK) or Radio Shack (US)?

Comment: Thanks. RS=Radiospares UK. I see the similarity with Sea Talk, but mine is definitely not hermetically sealed. BTW, I wondered if EM= E-Mark, but I couldn't see any similar product on their site.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a LV AC connector. I recognize them as connectors used for AC halogen garden lights. Difficult to match it wit a connector name of specific type. These connectors are often proprietary.