# Identification of polarized 2-pin connector used for low voltage lighting

Tags: identification, connector, 12v

I am currently working on some outdoor low voltage wiring/lighting for our house. I received some NOS high quality fixtures that I hope to use IF I can figure out what connector this is on the end of the fixtures.

Here is a picture of the connector.

[image: Small 2 pin connector]

- 2 pins
- External diameter 11 mm
- Internal diameter 6 mm, keyed/D-shaped
- Pins approx. 4 mm center to center
- Ribbed/ridges on the outside of the connector, but not threaded
- No name or branding on anything.

I picked up some cheap 2-pin IP65 LED pigtails assuming that is what they were, but I was completely wrong.

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated so I don't have to cut and rewire each fixture.

Comment: Remarkably similar, but appears to be different dimensions: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/512880/2028

Comment: looks like a connector that IKEA uses on some of their low voltage lights